# Lenovo tab 3 7" TB3-710F Android 5.0.1 won't start after installing wrong TWRP

Tags: twrp, tablet, lenovo

Basically I wanted to root it and every TWRP I tried came up an error that the file was too big,. moments later I tried different versions..many other versions btw,, scaling down to the smallest in size was 2.0.1.2 I think..

Anyway, it got stuck in a bootloop for about 2 hours. Mind you the computer makes the beep everytime I connected it and reconnected, so I thought it's still alive. Now, it won't turn on and I've tried most of the method's to get it flashed but nothing even lights it up... brick

I have tried most XDA and Google without any possible fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROOT Lenovo tab 3 7" TB3-710F Android 5.0.1. also to that's stuck in FASTBOOT MODE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212600/root-lenovo-tab-3-7-tb3-710f-android-5-0-1-also-to-thats-stuck-in-fastboot-mo)

Comment: I added it  it the notes with a link because they are different questions

Comment: the size of recovery partition is 16 MiB (hex 0x0000000001000000 = 16777216 bytes)

Comment: @alecxs Tried all that. I even tried different ADB commands. Error no device detected or waiting for device,...,........I even tried kingroot, to see if it would recognise anything...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that really detailled answer, dear alecxs.. At first it didnt work because i had the wrong ROM , than i take the correct one , followed the tutorial really exactly from 1-20 and what should i say , i reanimated this Tablet which stucked in a bootloop a long while. Workes well now .. I struggled a little bit with Google Play Services which i cant update  but i kicked them after i rooted the tablet and reinstalled them manually again..

Thanks for this great tutorial

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) - download the latest ADB and Fastboot binaries

[2](http://www.google.com/search?q=MT65xx%20Preloader%20USB%20drivers) - install MediaTek MT65xx USB VCOM Preloader USB Drivers

[image: SP_FLASH_TOOL_MediaTek_MT65xx_USB-VCOM_Preloader_Drivers.png] [enlarge view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0ypowtf1oskzxm/SP_FLASH_TOOL_MediaTek_MT65xx_USB-VCOM_Preloader_Drivers.png?dl=0&raw=1)
Note: This driver does only appear for less a second (and during flash/ readback) [watch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2XWTAYmNUo)

[3](https://spflashtools.com) - install MediaTek SP Flash Tool

[4](https://www.7-zip.org) - install 7-zip

[5](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Android-based-Tablets-and/where-is-firmware-for-TB3-710F-essentials-tablet/td-p/4329998) - download Stock ROM, extract it

6 - remove the checksum at end of (Stock ROM) MT8127_Android_scatter.txt (last two lines):

```
# [huaqin]
# checkSum = 0x0f5e
```

7 - open the (Stock ROM) MT8127_Android_scatter.txt file in SP Flash Tool -> Download
(and SP_Flash_Tool\MTK_AllInOne_DA.bin as Download Agent, if not already selected)
WARNING: Make sure not to "Format All + Download" **devices with secure boot** or flash using "Firmware Upgrade" option. This will damage/hard brick your device

8 - **de-select** the check box **"preloader"** (EMMC_BOOT)

[9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QprU7yvLwTI) - remove the battery

[image: www_youtube_com_watch_v_QprU7yvLwTI]

10 - click **Download** in SP Flash Tool

[image: SP_FLASH_TOOL_flash_ROM_TB3-710F_S000028_170316_ROW.png] [enlarge view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2mvazfqo6n53g6/SP_FLASH_TOOL_flash_ROM_TB3-710F_S000028_170316_ROW.png?dl=0&raw=1)

11 - **connect** Tablet to PC using USB Cable
(Note: the flashing starts immediately when connected. if nothing happens, wait for the drivers recognized first time, disconnect and repeat from step 7)

12 - wait for green checkmark **Download Ok**

13 - insert the battery

14 - press and **hold** Volume Up Button

15 - disconnect the USB Cable (still **holding** Volume Up)

16 - reconnect the USB Cable (still holding)
(Note: you may hear multiple connecting sounds - don't release the Volume Up Button yet)

17 - when Android system recovery appears, **release** Volume Up Button

18 - select **Reboot to bootloader** with Volume Down, confirm with Power (or Volume Up sometimes)

19 - open the platform_tools folder from **cmd.exe** (as Administrator)

20 - unlock the bootloader by typing following commands:

```
fastboot oem unlock
fastboot reboot
```

Note: If you want to flash custom recovery with SP Flash Tool, recovery.img must fit the size 16 MiB.
If the bootloader is unlocked, you can test the recovery before flashing, then flash from fastboot instead:

```
fastboot boot "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\recovery_twrp302_Lenovo_TB3-710F.img"  
fastboot flash recovery "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\recovery_twrp302_Lenovo_TB3-710F.img"
```

Comment: Tried all that. I even tried different ADB commands. Error no device detected or waiting for device,...,........I even tried kingroot, to see if it would recognise anything...

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the reply brb

Comment: step 10 nothing happens I click download and everything just gets greyed out and I plug in the device and I can hear the sound but nothing happens absolutely nothing I've tried all different ADB commands to start server it says the server is out of date and also the device is not detected in a VB anymore after the bootloop I think I killed it

Comment: thats not possible except you flashed a wrong preloader. can you hear one sound, or two? open device manager (com ports): between the two sounds, can you see the driver for a second? i attached a screenshot

Comment: thanks for your patience this is really tricky one it beeps twice and here is the new image

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ifYuUum.jpg

Comment: I don't think I've got the correct stock ROM for it each one I download has different codes at the end of them I've downloaded three different roms all for the same device this is really confusing I'm pretty sure I've got wrong rom. I think we're just going to start at square one and but I'm going to need a link if you can to the correct ROM file for this device because this is doing my head in at your leisure of course if you've got time I can do a Google search in the meantime but I've already got about 20  tabs open

Comment: the ROMs provided in answer are confirmed working. The two sounds indicating that preloader is still working, no worry it is not hard bricked. from your picture i can not see you installed preloader drivers. it is under (Ports COM & LPT), you missed step 2

Comment: ITS WORKING thanking you muchly. But can you pleas show me the steps to install the TWRP IMG file. I definitely don't want to brick it again.. my mind is like jelly and I lost the page of rooting it with the recovery img

Comment: Its all there, just follow step 20) fastboot commands

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GKdzQQw.jpg