# How to fix phone rejecting root

Tags: rooting

I have infinix x559c I have tried using root using Spflashtool and also fastboot it didn't work even when I unlock bootloader it flashed successfully but it didn't boot to recovery and it shows below my recovery "Api supported :3 " how can I fix it .

I used the guide here : https://wap.infinix.club/forum/736/969855

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: thanks for the link to tutorial. unfortunately these are just links behind links. would you mind posting the exact steps YOU did, please?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212931